# Como usar Packages no Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, composer, packages

Sou novato no framework Laravel 4. No Laravel 3 era simples usar Bundles.
Na versão 4 foi removido o uso dos Bundles e passou a usar Packages, mas não entendi como se usa, mesmo vendo na documentação. Por exemplo, em que pasta é colocada, no `Composer` onde é carregado etc..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O composer simplifica e unifica a distribuição de código no PHP, não existe muita diferença, porem os bundles para Laravel 3 em sua maioria não são compatíveis com o Laravel 4.

Pelo composer, cada pacote que deseje instalar é uma dependencia do projeto, então, editando o arquivo composer.json, você deve adicionar o pacote em questão na sessão require, para pesquisar os pacotes, você pode usar o packagist.org

Veja um exemplo, existe um Pacote de geradores para o Laravel 4, feito pelo Jeffrey Way, se eu quero usá-lo no projeto, devo adicionar o pacote ao composer.json, na sessão require

```jason
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
    "way/generators": "dev-master"
},
```

A Linha `"laravel/framework": "4.0.*"` já existia, adicionei a linha "way/generators": "dev-master"

Isso ainda não faz nada no projeto, para que a biblioteca seja baixada, execute na raíz do projeto o comando:

```
php composer.phar update
```

Ou se o composer estiver instalado Globalmente em seu ambiente

```
composer update
```

Feito isso, o fonte do pacote estará disponível na pasta vendor, e será carregado automaticamente pelo autoloader do Composer, não precisa usar include ou require.

Cada pacote pode ser usado separadamente, ou como no caso do pacote "Generators" do exemplo, ele integra com o Laravel 4, bastando adicionar esse linha:

```
'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider'
```

ao arquivo app/config/app.php, na sessão providers.

Antes de tentar entender os Pacotes para Laravel 4, tente estudar um pouco mais o Composer, é uma ferramenta fenomenal e indispensável para os programadores PHP.

Espero ter sido claro.

Comment: Era exatamente esse o uso que não estava entendendo, sobre o composer ja sei algumas coisas dele, o problema estava nos locais mesmo, muito obrigado

Comment: Considere ler a documentação de Cada Pacote, praticamente todos os pacotes para Laravel 4 tem instruções de instalação

Answer (score 2):

Como complemento à resposta que já foi dado, recomendo o uso da instalação do pacote desejado diretamente pela linha de comando, pois o `Laravel`, por possuir muitas dependências, faz com que o `Composer` leia todas elas, verificando biblioteca por biblioteca, para ver se existe uma nova versão.

Há casos onde esse comportamento não é desejado, por exemplo, quando quero instalar apenas uma biblioteca nova, sem mexer com as outras que já estão instaladas (e evitar atrasos, é claro).

Então, para isso, você utiliza o comando `composer.phar require` ou `composer require` (se tiver instalado globalmente).

Por exemplo, para adicionar uma biblioteca específica, poderia fazer assim:

```
 composer require wallacemaxters/timer 1.*
```

Ele iria instalar somente a biblioteca citada acima e, automaticamente, a incluiria como dependência no seu arquivo `composer.json`.